# Nougat: force to enter PIN and disable fingerprint every hour or every 10th time

Tags: lock-screens, 7.0-nougat, fingerprint

Is it possible to set Android 7 Nougat to ask for the PIN every hour or every 10th time, when using fingerprint to unlock a phone? The fingerprint unlocking is very convenient, but it seems not that safe, reading the following article:

[**That Fingerprint Sensor on Your Phone Is Not as Safe as You Think**](https://mobile.nytimes.com/2017/04/10/technology/fingerprint-security-smartphones-apple-google-samsung.html)